# Scroll a list item such that it becomes visible?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a list with a bunch of elements. Usually a scrollbar is required to show them all. I add items to the list at runtime. Is there some way to scroll a particular list element such that it is ensured to be visible?:

```
<ul id='parent'>
  <li>blah</li>
  ...
  <li id='nthItem'>blah</li>
</ul>

$('#parent').scrollChildToVisible('nthItem');
```

something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To scroll to an element you can use [**.animate()**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Here's an example of a function that scrolls to a jQuery selector (like an ID):

```
  // This is a function that scrolls to $(selector)
function goToByScroll(selector){
      // Scroll
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top},
        'slow');
}
```

You can trigger this function whenever it is necessary. For example right after you've added the element in question:

```
  // Append item
$("#parent").append("<li id='nthItem'>blah</li>");

  // Scroll to item using function above. 
goToByScroll("#nthItem");
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tNhLa/)**

Finally, to select an `id` in jQuery use

```
$("#nthItem") // correct for an ID
```

not

```
$("nthItem") // incorrect
```