# How to scroll to a new added entry in MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've created a DB application in MVC 4 using EntityFramework. It works okay, nevertheless I couldn't find the way of scrolling new added item to my table. Is it possible to scroll to a new row in DB applications in MVC? Like in DataGrid, for example:

```
  StudentDataGridDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(StudentDataGrid.SelectedItem)
```

Maybe there is a way to scroll to a row in MVC? Any advice or help would be very clarifying.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906881/how-to-scroll-to-a-new-added-entry-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use javascript for this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644927/scroll-a-list-item-such-that-it-becomes-visible) to know how. You should identify the added element somehow so you can reference it from your javascript.